# icons disappear from desktop when app updates

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts

On KitKat when I have a shortcut on the desktop and the app updates the shortcut on the desktop disappears, is there a way to stop this from happening?

Comment: Does this happen with _all_ apps? I have noticed this with earlier versions 4.4.x, but only very occasionally.

Comment: This appears to be fixed with an update from Feb  2014